# LINQ Query to put data in a nested object

Tags: c#, linq

I am working on writing a C# LINQ query to get data from a SQL table below

Table1

```
Id Status SubStatus
1  Review Pending 
2  Review Complete
3  Review Approved
4  Review Denied    
5  Info   Processing
6  Info   Pending
7  Info   Requested
8  Info   Received
9  Approval Approved
10 Review Approved
```

From the above table I would like to put the data in an object like below

```
public class LastStatusDto
    {
        public string StatusName { get; set; }
        public int StatusId { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<LastStatusChildDataDto> drillDownData { get; set; }
    }

public class LastStatusChildDataDto
{
    public string SubStatusName { get; set; }      
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

and the sample result(for Status "Review") looks like below

```
            {
              "statusName": "Review",
              "statusId": 0,
              "count": 5,
              "drillDownData": 
              [{
               "subStatusName":"Approved",
               "count":2 
              },
              {
               "subStatusName":"Complete",
               "count":1 
              },
             {
              "subStatusName":"Pending",
              "count":1 
              },
              {
               "subStatusName":"Denied",
               "count":1 
              },
            ]
        }
```

Whats a good way to write a LINQ query for the above scenario. I tried grouping by `status` but not able to figured a way to put `substatuses` in the nested object like below

```
var res = from status in context.Table1
          group status by status.Status into s

          select new LastStatusDto
          {
               Count = s.Count(),
               StatusName = s.Key,
               drilldownData = {/* ? */}                          
          };
```

Comment: Why is `StatusId` a property of `LastStatusDto` if it's an aggregate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
 var res = table1.GroupBy(t => t.Status)
            .Select(g => new LastStatusDto()
            {
                StatusId = 0,
                StatusName = g.Key,
                Count = g.Count(),
                drillDownData = g.GroupBy(s => s.SubStatus)
                    .Select(st => new LastStatusChildDataDto()
                    {
                        SubStatusName = st.Key,
                        Count = st.Count()
                    })
            });
```

As I mentioned in a comment above, `StatusId` has no place as a property of `LastStatusDto` because it's an aggregate so I set it `0` just to match your structure.

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks