# multiple grouping linq nested DTO not translating well

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, dto

This is a .NET Core Web API Task method. I have a flat table that I need to convert into a nested DTOs. The first DTO works but I can't seem to get the second DTO to nest after grouping.

I know I have done the grouping correctly. I am just not sure the second level nesting of the DTO is done correctly, it complains about not being able to translate to some type.
[LINQ Query to put data in a nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46793008/linq-query-to-put-data-in-a-nested-object)

Can someone point me in the right track?

```
 public async Task<List<PointCardViewModel>> GetPointCards()        {
        var data = (from s in db.Students
                    join dc in db.DailyCards on s.StudentId equals dc.StudentId
                    join dcli in db.DailyCardLineItems on dc.CardId equals dcli.CardId
                    join dcob in db.DailyCardOtherBehaviors on dc.CardId equals dcob.CardId
                    select new
                    {
                        s.StudentName,
                        s.StudentGrade,
                        dc.CardId,
                        dc.CardDate,
                        dcli.ClassParticipationPoints,
                        dcli.AssignmentCompletionPoints,
                        dcli.BonusHomeworkPoints,
                        dcli.ClassPeriod,
                        dcob.PersonalAppearancePoints,
                        dcob.LunchPoints,
                        dcob.RecessOtherPoints,
                        dcob.AmHomeroomPoints,
                        dcob.PmHomeroomPoints
                    });

        var queryPointCards = (data
                                 .GroupBy(x => new
                                 {
                                     x.CardId,
                                     x.StudentGrade,
                                     x.StudentName,
                                     x.CardDate,
                                     x.PersonalAppearancePoints,
                                     x.LunchPoints,
                                     x.RecessOtherPoints,
                                     x.AmHomeroomPoints,
                                     x.PmHomeroomPoints
                                 })
                                .Select(x => new PointCardViewModel()
                                {
                                    CardId = x.Key.CardId,
                                    StudentName = x.Key.StudentName,
                                    Grade = x.Key.StudentGrade,
                                    EvaluationDate = x.Key.CardDate,
                                    PersonalAppearancePoints = x.Key.PersonalAppearancePoints,
                                    LunchPoints = x.Key.LunchPoints,
                                    RecessOtherPoints = x.Key.RecessOtherPoints,
                                    AMHomeRoomPoints = x.Key.AmHomeroomPoints,
                                    PMHomeRoomPoints = x.Key.PmHomeroomPoints,

                                    //LineItems = null  --> This works!! But not the below
                                    LineItems = x.Select(c => new LineItemViewModel
                                    {
                                        ClassPeriod = c.ClassPeriod,
                                        BonusHomeworkPoints = c.BonusHomeworkPoints,
                                        ClassParticipationPoints = c.ClassParticipationPoints,
                                        AssignmentCompletionPoints = c.AssignmentCompletionPoints
                                    })
                                }
                              )
                          ).ToListAsync();

        if (db != null)
        {
            return await queryPointCards;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have hit limitation of Grouping. After groping you cannot access to group items. Only fields from 'Key' and aggregation functions are allowed.

So just put `data.AsEnumerable()` and do grouping on the client side.

Comment: What do you mean by grouping on the client side? I am trying to do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50973631/linq-query-to-object-with-nested-list

Comment: After AsEnumerable() data is materialized and grouping provided on the client side. Answer with link is wrong, It may work with EF 2.1, but not with latest versions.

Comment: Thank you so much. That helped me a lot ..I was so lost!!